# Remove duplicate row based on duplicate entry of one column

Tags: shell, solaris

I have below content in one text file. There are some duplicate entry in 3rd column. I want to remove duplicate row based on the 3rd column.

```
Row file:
2018-01-21 00:43:46,25,aabbtd,281727,223,01939900349
2018-01-21 00:43:41,26,aabbtd,281725,229,01939900348
2018-01-21 00:43:43,23,aabbtd,2817276,226,01939900345
2018-01-21 00:43:43,28,aa454,2817275,224,01939900344
2018-01-21 00:43:44,22,aa454,2817272,222,01939900341

Required file format:
2018-01-21 00:43:46,25,aabbtd,281727,223,01939900349
2018-01-21 00:43:43,28,aa454,2817275,224,01939900344
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use awk to do that.

```
awk -F',' '!seen[$3]++' filename
```

should work for you.

-F defines the delimiter

$3 holds the column 3 content

**On Solaris use /usr/ bin/nawk or /usr/xpg4/ bin/awk**

Comment: I have tried with this command but getting below error.

"awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
"

Comment: Oh, it's Solaris... Use /usr/bin/nawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk to be able to use it with -F